# How to get return value when user hits cancel on parameter request input box in MS Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

My program exports all objects in my database to excel files. That works great. Some of these queries have parameter requests which brings up a input box (not a part of my code). When I enter values it works fine, but when I hit cancel I would like to be able to skip over that query and not export it, but instead I get the error:

> Run-time error '3021':
>
> Reserved Error

When I press Debug, it brings me to this line in my code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, obj.Name, path, True, obj.Name
```

Which I understand why since that is the export to excel line.

I've seen other questions similar to this but this was with user created input boxes. I'm wondering if there is a similar approach to this, somehow getting the return value from this parameter request input box and using that value to tell my program to do something.

Also, if I enter values for those boxes, it goes to the next part of my code where it exports a 30 page report to word. There is a box that comes up counting the pages that says

> Now outputting "examplefile" to "example path"

There is one button which is "Cancel". If I press cancel on that I get the error:

> Run-time error '2501;:
>
> The OutputTo action was canceled

and brings me to this line in my code:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, obj.Name, acFormatRTF, pathLabel4.Caption & "\" & obj.Name & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".rtf"
```

Again I understand why because this is where I'm exporting my report to a word document but how can I check if the user hits cancel or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but error trapping would give you the option to skip the query and export:

```
On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
...'Your code
PROC_ERR:
IF Err.Number = 2501
  Exit Sub 'assuming the rest of the code should be aborted.
End If
IF Err.Number = 3021
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Based on your comments about many parameters, and your original question, I thought of another possible solution.

There is a way to build a custom parameter dialog box that pops up instead of the default. This should also give you more flexibility in executing your code, since you can create a cancel button that works exactly the way you want it to. This is more like "building a new form," which I know you didn't want to do, but systematically could work the same way it is now. For a walkthrough, see [this](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut08.htm) link.

Comment: That is basically how to do it. A better approach would be to create a form with textboxes for the user to input the values, then modify the code to pass these values to the queries skipping those where empty values were given.

Comment: Let me add: in errors like 2501, you want to know the user has aborted the action, and pause execution. It seems to me Access tends to use Error handling as a legitimate method of passing data to and from a running process. As for error 3021, it just happens to be an error, The query is missing data and can't execute...

Comment: @Gustav , Can you add parameters by code to a query in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`?

Comment: @Christopher D. I would accept this answer but I want to see if there's a more efficient way. Seems a little weird that the language treats the user hitting cancel as an error. If that's how it is then I can accept that but until I find out for sure I'm keeping it open for other people to answer. (Your code did work by the way, thanks!)

Comment: To clarify, hitting cancel is an error. Your query requires a parameter, and if you don't pass it one, it cannot execute. @gustav made a good point about building controls on a form to enter your parameters, then you won't deal with the error. Whether there's a different way of handling the cancel click is unclear. No worries about the answer, I'm just here to learn and help teach!

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought cancel would be some sort of "End" command which terminates the program

Comment: Also as for adding controls. I am trying to keep the form as simple as possible for the users. Having these popups after the click "export to excel" is more systematic I guess and won't overload with information. Plus there are a lot of parameters

Comment: It's vague for sure, but you're really just cancelling the parameter prompt, not the program.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you are not using the popup, parameter request dialogs. There are many pitfalls with them such as what you are encountering, query throws an error if it doesn't get its value, and there is no validation at all.

I like to use the `Range.CopyFromRecordset` to move data into Excel as there is a lot more control over how the data are formatted and what data go where.

Let's say on your form you have some combobox with valid input values `combo1`. Then when you want to export to Excel you can call this on a button click

```
If PassesValidation(Combo1) Then
    Dim e As New Exporter
    Dim views As ADOX.views
    Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
    Set cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

    Dim proc As ADOX.Procedure 'because it has an input parameter
    Dim cmd As adodb.Command
    Set proc = cat.Procedures("ParameterTestQuery")
    Set cmd = proc.Command
    cmd.Parameters("pChangeType") = Combo1
    Dim rs As adodb.Recordset
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    e.CreateExcelReport rs
End If
```

Your `PassesValidation` can either take input parameters or look at the form directly. Either way this step is basically what you are doing instead of catching an error when a user clicks out of the Input Parameter dialog box.

The supporting code for this looks like

```
Public Function CreateExcelReport(ExportRecordSet As adodb.Recordset) As Excel.Workbook

    Dim wbExp As Excel.Workbook, wsExport As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ApXL As Excel.Application
    Dim rsReportableErrors As adodb.Recordset

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ApXL = GetExcelApplication

    On Error GoTo DoStuff_Error
    Set wbExp = ApXL.Workbooks.Add

    Set wsExport = wbExp.Sheets(1)

    Set wsExport = MoveRecordsetToSheet(wsExport, ExportRecordSet, options)

    wsExport.Cells.WrapText = False
    Dim c As Integer
    For c = 0 To ExportRecordSet.Fields.Count
        wsExport.Columns(c).AutoFit
        If wsExport.Columns(c).ColumnWidth > (35) Then
            wsExport.Columns(c).ColumnWidth = 35
        End If
    Next c
    wsExport.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Set CreateExcelReport = wbExp
Exit_DoStuff:
    ApXL.Visible = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function


End Function

Private Function MoveRecordsetToSheet(sht As Excel.Worksheet, rst As adodb.Recordset) As Excel.Worksheet
    Set sht = MakeFirstRowFieldNames(sht, rst)
    sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    sht.Columns.AutoFit
    Set MoveRecordsetToSheet = sht
End Function

Private Function MakeFirstRowFieldNames(sht As Excel.Worksheet, rst As adodb.Recordset) As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim fld As adodb.Field
    Dim col As Integer
    col = 1
    With sht
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        With .Cells(1, col)

            .Value = fld.Name

            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192)
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
        With .Cells.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        col = col + 1
    Next fld
     .UsedRange.AutoFilter
    End With
    Set MakeFirstRowFieldNames = sht
End Function


Function GetExcelApplication(Optional ByRef WasANewInstanceReturned As Boolean) As Excel.Application

    If ExcelInstanceCount > 0 Then
        Set GetExcelApplication = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        WasANewInstanceReturned = False
    Else
        Set GetExcelApplication = New Excel.Application
        WasANewInstanceReturned = True
    End If
End Function

Function ExcelInstanceCount() As Integer
    Dim objList As Object, objType As Object, strObj As String
    strObj = "Excel.exe"
    Set objType = GetObject("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("select * from win32_process where name='" & strObj & "'")
    ExcelInstanceCount = objType.Count
End Function
```

You'll end up with a nicely formatted Excel file. In my opinion the biggest advantage to this is that the file is opened **but not saved**. This means the end user can save it wherever they want or they can close it out with no stray files left around if they don't like what they see.

Note that this all requires references to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library` (ADODB) , `Microsoft ADO Ext. for DDL and Security` (ADOX), and `Microsoft Excel Object Library` (Excel).